# Searching and replacing with Notepad++, text color

Tags: xml, text, translation, notepad++

I'm working on the translation of some xml files and I must find a way to speed up my work. I am using the text editor Notepad++ to translate these file. So, I wonder if there is any way to search for the text in black color?
The strings that I need to translated are in black (PHRASE tags)and orange (CDATA tags)

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the **contents** of the file with the **style** the contents are shown in notepad++ which ultimately depends on the extension part of the filename (If you rename the file to an unknown extension you will notice that notepad++ does not highlight the styles)

So, your question is really, how to Search and Replace using the style logic of notepad++. Unfortunately, notepad++ does not provide a search option for styles.

However you have other options. You need to locate the PHRASE and CDATA tags and apply your own replace/translate strategy. There are fundamentally two options to automate such a global replace: Maybe a regex replace or maybe a key macro.

Comment: what? locating the data or replacing it?

Comment: see notepad++ help on how to search; then try searching for PHRASE or CDATA. After that, record a macro to replace the contents that are next to it. The other alternative requires you know regex, do you?

Comment: I'm looking at somethings here http://www.regular-expressions.info . But, I'm still lost

Comment: Expand your question with some detailed examples on what you have in your xml file and how you want to translate it. Maybe it's not suitable for simple search and replace and you need a full XLST solution.